# "CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination" errors when running the official sample code "Current Location" in my Iphone5s

Tags: mapkit, cgbitmapcontextcreate

When I run the sample code "Current Location" in my Iphone5s, It always appears the following errors.

```
Nov 26 20:24:00 dev CurAddress[571] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 5 integer bits/component; 16 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast; 512 bytes/row.
2013-11-26 20:24:00.979 CurAddress[571:9503] vImage decode failed, falling back to CG path.
Nov 26 20:24:00 dev CurAddress[571] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 5 integer bits/component; 16 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast; 512 bytes/row.
2013-11-26 20:24:00.990 CurAddress[571:9003] vImage decode failed, falling back to CG path.
…
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this problem on both iPhone5 and iPad4 with iOS7, as well as emulators. Even if I dragged the MKMapview onto the ViewController from widget collection and did nothing afterwards, error messages still occurred. However, it seems that my codes work well regardless of these error messages.